# using python map to apply type func in tuple to a list of strings

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

I have a list d of 'tokens' all strings and a list of tuples of the form (fieldname,fieldtype)
For Example

```
ds = ['1','1','1','1','1']
fs = [('type',str),('value',int),('hidden',bool),('length',int),('pieces',str)
```

and I want to make a dict v having the following form

```
v = {'type':'1','value',1,'hidden':True,'length':1,'pieces','1')
```

What I currently have is very inefficient (I map the type func in the tuple to elements in the list one at a time)

```
v = {}
for j in xrange(len(fs)):
    v[fs[j]] = map(fs[j][1],[ds[j]])[0]
```

How can I make this efficient and easy to read? I've tried lambdas, etc. If this were a one time thing I would just do it manually but there are multiple lists of tuples some of them 50 elements long.

Comment: Thanks all for below answers so promptly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
>>> items = iter(ds)
>>> v = {a: b(next(items)) for a, b in fs}
>>> v
{'type': '1', 'hidden': True, 'pieces': '1', 'length': 1, 'value': 1}
```

That is what I would probably do.

Comment: used as it seems most efficient, never even thought of a dict comprehension.

Comment: @dvp It is most efficient as you are only holding one item in memory at a time, but with `zip` you iterate twice unnecessarily. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 4):

You can [zip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) the lists and apply function defined in `fs` to the appropriate `ds` value:

```
>>> ds = ['1','1','1','1','1']
>>> fs = [('type',str),('value',int),('hidden',bool),('length',int),('pieces',str)]
>>> {key: f(value) for (key, f), value in zip(fs, ds)}
{'hidden': True, 'type': '1', 'length': 1, 'value': 1, 'pieces': '1'}
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea (not much readable):

```
>>> v = {t[0]:t[1](ds[i]) for i,t in enumerate(fs)}
>>> v
{'hidden': True, 'type': '1', 'length': 1, 'value': 1, 'pieces': '1'}
```